# Problem with my caesar cipher using unicode

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

This is for python task for my class I'm trying to make a caesar cipher using unicode. I've gotten the lowercase to loopback to a if it passes z. But I can't seem to get the uppercase to work.

Here is my function code:

```
def rot(text, key):

    cypher_text = ''
   
    for char in text:
       
        if char.isalpha():
           
            num = ord(char)
            
            if (num + key) > 122 and 90:
                
                x = (num + key) - 122 or 90
                
                cypher_text += chr(x + ord('a') - 1)
            
            elif num + key <= 122 and 90:
               
                cypher_text += chr(num + key)
      
        else:
            cypher_text += char
    
    return cypher_text
```

For example if I enter Hello! and enter 19 as the rotation key

It prints this `[xeeh!`

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: `if (num + key) > 122 and 90:` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: if the value of num + key are larger then  122 or 90 it should loopback to the first letter

Comment: if `num + key` is greater than 122, it will then always be greater than 90

Comment: So i should put a separate if for 90?

Comment: Yes. First check `>122` and then in `else if` check with 90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this -

```
def rot(text, key):
    cypher_text = ''
    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            num = ord(char)
            if char.isupper():
                num = (num - ord('A') + key) % 26 + ord('A')
            else:
                num = (num - ord('a') + key) % 26 + ord('a')
            cypher_text += chr(num)
        else:
            cypher_text += char

    return cypher_text
```

For the calculation, you can get the displacement from the first letter (i.e. 'A' or 'a'). Then add that to the key and wrap around using % 26. Like if lets say `char` is 'H' and `key` is 19, so after addition of displacement and key it will be greater than 26. `% 26` will wrap around to the proper displacement and it will also help if `key` is itself greater than 26. Adding `A` or `a` again will get the correct ciphered character